# Flowplayer's Lightbox Closing it using script?

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox, flowplayer

I am using Flowplayer's lightbox can anyone tell me how I can close the lightbox using script after 10 secs.

Basically when the page is opened the lightbox is triggered, and then numerous other scripts run in the background once completed the lightbox should close after 10 secs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //close it here
}, 10000);
```

Comment: thanks, but i also needed the script used to close the lightbox if poss.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the API docs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html), you would call the `close()` method on the `overlay()` pulled from the triggering element.  So, to to accomplish this after 10 seconds you would wrap this method in a `setTimeout` like mentioned:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.overlayTrigger').overlay().close();
}, 10000);
```